# In Ansible, how to move a line into a block?

Tags: ansible

I have a situation where I would like to include an existing line in a text file into a new block.

```
line 1
line 2
line in block
line 3
line 4
```

should become

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
# BEGIN MyBlock
line in block
other line in block
# END MyBlock
```

Creating the block of course involves the blockinfile module:

```
- blockinfile:
    path: /etc/myfile
    marker: "# {mark} MyBlock"
    block: |
      line in block
      other line in block
```

The lineinfile could be used to remove a line:

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/myfile
    line: 'line in block'
    state: absent
```

But this solution may remove the line within the block, instead of the original one.

Comment: You could check if "line in block" is located before an Ansible Block Marker. If that is not the case, then don't execute the `lineinfile` command. Would that be possible in your use-case?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's always feasible. For one, the line to be removed could either be before or after the block. For another, I can't think of an easy way to determine which comes first.

Comment: Hou could run it once to remove the line. And then don’t use the task anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Execute both the `lineinfile` AND the `blockinfile` in a row. The first one will remove it and the second one will include it. In the end, it will be in the right place. Dirtier than it could be, but it works.

**Update:** In that case a working idempotent solution would be:

```yaml
  - name: Slurp file
    slurp:
      src: myfile
    register: myfile

  - name: Remove line if not in block
    lineinfile:
      path: myfile
      line: 'line in block'
      state: absent
    when: >
      not (myfile.content
           | b64decode
           | regex_search('# BEGIN MyBlock(\n.*)*\nline in block(\n.*)*\n# END MyBlock'))

  - name: Add block
    blockinfile:
      path: myfile
      marker: "# {mark} MyBlock"
      block: |
        line in block
        other line in block
```

Comment: Thanks, but this really doesn't work, because on the next run, the lineinfile will remove the line from within the block. The blockinfile will restore it, but it will register as two changes. I.e., this approach is not idempotent.